# LibGDX - ImageButton and textures for touchDown and touchUp

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have problem with setting my `ImageButton`. I want to have two different textures in my `button`, first when `button` is `touchDown`, and second when my button is `touchUp`. But I all time have `touchUp` texture. Here is my code:

```
buttonUp_texture = assets.manager.get(assets.buttonUp);
Drawable buttonUp_drawable = new TextureRegionDrawable((new TextureRegion(buttonUp_texture)));

buttonDown_texture = assets.manager.get(assets.buttonDown);
Drawable buttonDown_drawable = new TextureRegionDrawable((new TextureRegion(buttonDown_texture)));

tapBtn = new ImageButton(buttonUp_drawable, buttonDown_drawable);
```

and `listener`:

```
    startButtonListener= new ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            Gdx.app.log("Button", "TouchDown");
            game.setScreen(gameScreen);
            return super.touchDown(event, x, y, pointer, button);
        }

        @Override
        public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            Gdx.app.log("Button", "TouchUp");
            super.touchUp(event, x, y, pointer, button);
        }
    };
```

Listeners work correctly so I dont know what is wrong.